# liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: does not exist

Tags: java, liquibase

I have given the liquibase changelog file

```
database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(ds.getConnection()));
String changelogPath = "SQL/liquibase/changeLogs/project-00-01-01-00.xml";
Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase(changelogPath, new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);
liquibase.update("%");
```

But always this error is thrown:

> INFO: Successfully released change log lock
>
> liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: SQL/liquibase/changeLogs/project-00-01-01-00.xml does not exist
> at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser.parseToNode(XMLChangeLogSAXParser.java:100)

This happens on a new macOS development environment; for Linux and Windows dev OS, this was never an issue.

I tried retrieving the working directory path and adjusting the String of the path accordingly, but that didn't help at all.

Comment: did u try /SQL/liquibase/changeLogs/project-00-01-01-00.xml ?

Comment: yes, I tried that as well